# Aggregating time series data to one variable

Tags: r, time-series

I have got various time series data for different observations. I want to represent one time series observation by **one aggregated variable**. The easiest one is to take the `mean` of the time series, but `mean` does not capture the variations in the observation over time. I thought of computing the distance (`dist`) between an arbitrary reference and the time series data.

I am curious to know if there is other technique that I could apply to fairly represent the time series observation by **one aggregation variable**? Is there any R package that I can use?

Thanks

Comment: What you ask is very much application dependent. Can you tell us more on what you are trying to achieve? For example, if your time series represents a stock the best approach would probably be very different than if you want to characterize an EEG signal.

Comment: The time series are traffic data (i.e., speed, count, spacing.... of vehicles on freeways over time on each day). The goal is to  summarize/aggregate each time series by one variable and then apply multi-dimensional scaling to cluster days of similar traffic characteristics.

Comment: Well in that case why do you require only one aggregation variable? Clustering can be done a number of variables...

Answer (score 2):

One of the goals of control charts is to aggregate information from a complex process into one or more univariate summary statistics. Depending on the process type (stationary, non-stationary etc) and the dimensionality of the process, different control charts can be used. This might suit you well - especially since you considered distances already.

Two simple control chart approaches to consider are the MEWMA and MCUSUM control charts. These methods are implmented in the [MSQC](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/MSQC/MSQC.pdf) package in R. Analytical procedures for these are implemented in the [spc package](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/spc/spc.pdf) in R. 
Montgomery's [Introduction to Statistical Process Control](http://eu.wiley.com/WileyCDA/WileyTitle/productCd-EHEP002023.html) provides implementation details, in clear, non-esoteric wording in case you would like to know more.

Both charts will work well if you don't have too many variables (since they require the inversion of a covariance matrix, which can become problematic if variables are highly correlated), and can handle some level of non-stationarity.

To use these methods, you must first train a model on data without faults (this may be no problem for you - perhaps you have none). This means you should select a value of the forgetting factor (MEWMA) or the reference value parameters (MCUSUM) based on a test set if possible. This can be done by cross-validation, or eye-balling it if you are in a rush and this is mostly for data exploratory purposes.

Once you have the parameters of the control charts, you can apply them "in the wild". This will return to you a univariate control chart statistic summarizing the information from your time series, as well as control limits indicating when your process is behaving atypically.